# How to measure overlap between a home range raster layer and a polygon in R

Tags: r, spatial, raster, overlap, r-sf

I have some tracking data and for which I calculate a home range. I want to measure the extent of the overlap between the home range raster and a protected area.

I am using the `amt` and `sf` packages but when I try to work with the raster I get an error:

> Error in UseMethod("st_as_sf") :    no applicable method for
>   'st_as_sf' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster',
>   'BasicRaster')"

```
# load packages
library(wdpar)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(amt)
library(adehabitatHR)

# download protected area data 
# (excluding areas represented as point localities)
sa_raw_pa_data <- wdpa_fetch(c("Malta"))
sa_raw_pa_data 

sa_raw_pa_data <- sa_raw_pa_data %>% filter(NAME == "Ghadira")

# reproject data
sa_pa_data <- st_transform(sa_raw_pa_data, 4326)

  sa_pa_data %>%
  st_set_geometry(NULL) %>%
  glimpse()

sa_pa_data$GIS_AREA <- st_area(sa_pa_data)
sa_pa_data

#' dissolve
sa_pa_data <-
  sa_pa_data %>%
  summarise(area = sum(GIS_AREA))

# create some random data
set.seed(123)
d = data.frame(long=runif(100,13.9324226,14.8267966), lat=runif(100,35.6029696,36.2852706))
d$id <- c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50))

trk <-
  mk_track(
    d,
    .x = long,
    .y = lat,
    id = id,
    crs = CRS(
      "+init=epsg:4326"
    ))

#' create the home ranges 
kde_shape_1 <- trk %>% filter(id == "A") %>%
  hr_kde(., levels = c(0.95))
kde_shape_2 <- trk %>% filter(id == "B") %>%
  hr_kde(., levels = c(0.95))

#' measure the overlap - HERE'S THE ERROR
kernel.sf = st_as_sf(kde_shape_1$ud)
st_intersect(kernel.sf, sa_pa_data)
```

Comment: You should provide a  *minimal, self-contained, reproducible* example. In other words, create a Raster object, an sf object and show what you want to do (the last line). Now you are showing many lines of code that are irrelevant to the question at hand, and that we cannot run as we do not have the data

Comment: This code should work as a self contained example so long as those packages are installed. I've removed some unnecessary plotting code but I want to preserve the way in which I get the protected area because I think this may be part of the issue.

Comment: Then you should test your assumption about the way you create the data, which is wrong, as the error message is very clear about what the problem is.

Comment: Yes I seem to be missing a step that would convert the rasterlayer into something that the sf package can work with.